# PHP Class not found from a different namespace

Tags: php, symfony, classnotfound, phpspec

I'm currently working on a Symfony2 project with Phpspec and I'm having problems to extend a Spec class described in a different namespace.

In my project, for instance, I'm having the following class described in `spec/Acme/Model/Foo/FooSpec.php` :

```
namespace spec\Acme\Model\Foo;

use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

abstract class FooSpec extends ObjectBehavior{
    //some code here
}
```

And I have another class in `spec/Acme/Model/Bar/BarSpec.php` extending `FooSpec` :

```
namespace spec\Acme\Model\Bar;

use spec\Acme\Model\Foo\FooSpec;

class BarSpec extends FooSpec{
    //some code here
}
```

When I try to run phpspec, I have the following error :

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'spec\Acme\Model\Foo\FooSpec' not found in /home/user/Projects/Acme/spec/Acme/Model/Bar/BarSpec.php on line 9`

The only way I found to make it work was to add the following line in `spec/Acme/Model/Bar/BarSpec.php`:

```
include('./spec/Acme/Model/Foo/FooSpec.php');
```

I don't know why I have to include this specific file to make it run, especially when the other classes (like `PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior`) are correctly found.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

---

Edit:

As suggested by @Phil and @Sheikh Heera in the comments, I tried to set up an `autoload` to register my spec namespace but it's not working neither. Here is what I tried so far :

```
require_once getcwd() . '/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php';

$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();

// register classes with namespaces
$loader->add('spec', getcwd().'/spec');

// activate the autoloader
$loader->register();
```

I also tried to modify the file `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` to add this :

```
return array(
    //some code here

    'spec' => array(getcwd() . '/spec'),
    //some more code

);
```

But still the same error. I also tried with `'spec' => array(getcwd())` or `$loader->add('spec', getcwd());` just to see what will happen and this time I get a `Cannot redeclare class` on another spec class.

---

My php version is `PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4 (cli)`.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you set up an autoloader for the `spec` namespace that PHPSpec is aware of?

Comment: [Check this](https://test-sf-doc-es.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/tools/autoloader.html), it may help.

Comment: @SheikhHeera and Phil, I updated my question

Comment: I believe this is because the creators of PHPSpec did not intend on your tests extending other tests.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: @CarlOwens, I'm doing this because I have an abstract class which is inherited by 3 other classes (at the moment). I don't want to copy paste the specifications of the abstract class in every child but I want to be sure that the 3 children have the same behaviour. Hence I want to make them extending the abstract class. You can have a look at this discussion : [PhpSpec - Issue #54](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec2/issues/54)

Marijn is doing the same as what I want to do.

Comment: @Lanlet hmmm interesting.  I have not felt the need to spec abstract classes, but I see your problem.  You do not want to duplicate test code across your three concrete classes.  I think I agree mostly with everzet's comments regarding incomplete classes, but it would be good if phpspec allowed some way of sharing your spec tests for cases such as yours.  Don't think I can help sorry :)

Comment: Call your FooSpec a FooBehavior. It is not a spec, but a base class for your specs (like the original ObjectBehavior).

Comment: @JakubZalas you're right, I made the necessary changes in my code. As I was talking about behavior in my question I should have thought about naming it the right way.

Comment: @CarlOwens I also agree with everzet's comments. I think the need to describe the behavior of an (incomplete) abstract class is a proof of bad design. Why I actually "chose" to do so is because in my case my FooSpec (or FooBehavior as stated by Jakub Zalas) is complete but will never be instanciated in my application. To be sure it won't be, I decided to define it as abstract. I'm only using it to give a complete base for other children. I would be pleased to continue this discussion if you have any suggestion (or anything else) to say. I found a "not so bad" way to autoload my namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more generic solution is to put the spec directory into the `autoload-dev` configuration of your composer.json:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-0": {
        "spec\\":""
    }
},
```

This way, composer will generate the namespace also for the specs, which should be on the root of the repository:

```
return array(
     'spec\\' => array($baseDir . '/'),
     ...
);
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution but forgot to update my answer. I accepted your answer so others can see it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally, what I actually did to "solve" my "problem", as suggested by Phil and Sheikh Heera in the comments, is to autoload my namespace so it is recognized by spec.

Here is what I did to make it work :

- I added the following line to the file `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` :

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);
return array(
    //some code
    'spec\\Acme\\Behavior' => array(getcwd()),
    //some code
);
```

- Then I created the following folder structure :

```
    │── spec
    │  └── Acme
    │     └── Behavior
    │        └── FooBehavior.php
```

- I declared the namespace in `spec/Acme/Behavior/FooBehavior.php` this way :

```
namespace spec\Acme\Behavior;
```

- And used it in `spec/Acme/Model/Bar/BarSpec.php` as following :

```
use spec\Acme\Behavior\FooBehavior;

class BarSpec extends FooBehavior{
    //...
}
```

I know this is not the best practice because everytime someone will be working on this project it will have to reproduce manually the first step. So if you have any better idea, please feel free to comment or post an answer.